# Javascript Regular Expression - Filter only integer string also negative

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex validation of a string and I want to check if string is an integer string, positive or negative.

I tryed to create my expression and I'm able to filter only digit with symbol '-' but I can't match as true string that begin with '-' (optional) and contains any digit at the end.

This is my try:

```
    var intRegex = /^[-?\d]+$/g;

    console.log(intRegex.test('55')); // true
    console.log(intRegex.test('artgz')); // false
    console.log(intRegex.test('55.3')); // false
    console.log(intRegex.test('-55')); // true
    console.log(intRegex.test('--55')); // true but I don't want this true
    console.log(intRegex.test('5-5')); // true but I don't want this true
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `/^-?\d+$/`, you want hyphen(-) only 0 or 1 times, so you use ? after -, and \d can be 1 or more times so use + for \d only.

```js
var intRegex = /^[-]?\d+$/g;

console.log(intRegex.test('55')); // true
console.log(intRegex.test('artgz')); // false
console.log(intRegex.test('55.3')); // false
console.log(intRegex.test('-55')); // true
console.log(intRegex.test('--55')); // true but I don't want this true
console.log(intRegex.test('5-5')); // true but I don't want this true
```

Comment: `[-]` is better written as `-`.